# How to disable transfer of spl-token?

Tags: spl-token, metaplex

Like `spl-token authorize <TOKEN_ADDRESS> mint --disable` is there any way I can disable the transfer of the token making it an EVM equivalent of Soulbound Tokens (SBT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can freeze a token account if you have the freeze-authority

`spl-token freeze ...`

transfers cannot be made from the frozen account. You can `thaw` the account to unfreeze it.

docs are here: https://spl.solana.com/token

Comment: Thanks, but there’s a little catch that token should be created with `--enable-freeze`

Comment: Of course. So if its your own token, you can choose to do that. Or not :)